# Android app is crashing after clicking button

Tags: java, android

Android Studio is showing **open app again** app-crash when I click **sign up button**
The app is running fine but when I click the sign up button it crashes, also want to start new activity after sign up but the error is com

I think there is some problem with **button click listener** or **validation code** but don't know where this error is coming from.

following is my **java file code**:

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String TAG = "SignUp";
    private Vibrator vib;
    Animation animShake;
    private EditText signupInputName, signupInputEmail, signupInputPassword, signupInputDOB;
    private TextInputLayout signupInputLayoutName, signupInputLayoutEmail, signupInputLayoutPasword, signupInputLayoutDOB;
    private Button btnSignUp;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.sign_up_form);
        signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_name);
        signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_email);
        signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_Password);
        signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_DOB);

        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_name);
        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_email);
        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_Password);
        signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_DOB);

        btnSignUp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_signUp);
        animShake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getApplicationContext(), R.anim.shake);
        vib = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                register();
            }
        });
    }

    public void register() {
        submitForm();
        {
            if (!checkName() || !checkEmail() || !checkDOB() || !checkPassword()) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "signup failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                onSignupSuccess();
            }
        }
    }

    public void onSignupSuccess() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, tab1Petrol.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    private void submitForm() {
        if (!checkName()) {
            signupInputName.setAnimation(animShake);
            signupInputName.startAnimation(animShake);
            vib.vibrate(125);
            return;
        }
        if (!checkEmail()) {
            signupInputEmail.setAnimation(animShake);
            signupInputEmail.startAnimation(animShake);
            vib.vibrate(125);
            return;
        }
        if (!checkPassword()) {
            signupInputPassword.setAnimation(animShake);
            signupInputPassword.startAnimation(animShake);
            vib.vibrate(125);
            return;
        }
        if (!checkDOB()) {
            signupInputDOB.setAnimation(animShake);
            signupInputDOB.startAnimation(animShake);
            vib.vibrate(125);
            return;
        }
        signupInputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        signupInputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        signupInputLayoutPasword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        signupInputLayoutDOB.setErrorEnabled(false);
        Toast.makeText(this, "you are successfully Registered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    private boolean checkName() {
        if (signupInputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            signupInputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(true);
            signupInputLayoutName.setError("Please enter a Name");
            signupInputName.setError("valid Input Required");
            return false;
        }
        signupInputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkEmail() {
        String email = signupInputEmail.getText().toString().trim();
        if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
            signupInputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(true);
            signupInputLayoutEmail.setError("Please enter a Valid Email");
            signupInputEmail.setError("valid Input Required");
            requestFocus(signupInputEmail);
            return false;
        }
        signupInputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkPassword() {
        if (signupInputPassword.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
            signupInputLayoutPasword.setError("Please enter password");
            requestFocus(signupInputPassword);
            return false;
        }
        signupInputLayoutPasword.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    private boolean checkDOB() {
        try {
            boolean isDateValid = false;
            String[] s = signupInputDOB.getText().toString().split("/");
            int date = Integer.parseInt(s[0]);
            int month = Integer.parseInt(s[1]);

            if (date < 32 && month < 13)
                isDateValid = true;
            if (signupInputDOB.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() && isDateValid) {
                signupInputLayoutDOB.setError("Enter a valid D.O.B");
                requestFocus(signupInputDOB);
                signupInputDOB.setError("valid input required");
                return false;
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            signupInputLayoutDOB.setError("Enter a valid D.O.B");
            requestFocus(signupInputDOB);
            return false;
        }
        signupInputDOB.setError(null);
        return true;
    }

    private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
        return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
    }

    private void requestFocus(View view) {
        if (view.requestFocus()) {
            getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

**XML file code**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

           <EditText
               android:id="@+id/signup_input_name"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:ems="10"
               android:hint="@string/name" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_input_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:hint="Email" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_Password"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_input_Password"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:hint="Password" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_DOB"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/signup_input_DOB"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="Date of Birth" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gender_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="I am"
                android:fontFeatureSettings="Password"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:fontFamily="Password"/>
            <RadioGroup
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/gender_textView"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/male_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Male"
                    android:checked="true"/>
                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/Female_radio"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Female"/>
            </RadioGroup>
        </RelativeLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_signUp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />


    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your logcat errors.

Comment: with respect your code is not according to java conventions and have multiple errors.

Comment: First, you have lots of copy paste mistakes(findViewById parts). Second, your logic of checking fields is bad. Please revise them and edit your question.

Comment: When you are giving findviewId to TextInputlayout and edittext your name is same.

Comment: 1. The logcat tells you exactly where the error comes from. Trace the logic back from the lines mentioned by it. 2. Please read about a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Well for starters you are re-assigning the Input fields here, overwriting the previous one... I'm pretty sure the issue is because of this.

```
signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_name);
signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_email);
signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_Password);
signupInputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.signup_input_DOB);

signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_name);
signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.sign_up_email);
signupInputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout)  findViewById(R.id.sign_up_DOB);
```

The very first thing your code does after `onCreate()` is `checkEmail()`, and as I stated above, there is no `R.id.signup_input_email` assigned to `signupInputEmail`.

Your code will throw an exception here since `checkEmail()` refers to a NULL variable.

`if (!checkEmail()) { ... }`

Comment: Good catch! And the TextInputLayouts as well.